# Do we make a bracha on a talis, the night of Yom Kippur?

Tags: blessing, yom-kippur, evening-night

The mitzvah of tziztit does not apply at night, so when we wear a talis all of davening on Yom Kippur, starting this year on Friday night for Maariv, do we make a bracha when we put the talis on?

Is it better to put it on closer to mincha time to avoid any such issues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Mishna B'rura* 619:4 says to put on the *talis* during the day so as to be able to say the *b'racha* on it; one does not, he says, say the *b'racha* on it if putting it on at night. That's the way I read it; [CYLOR](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/CYLOR) for practical matters.

Comment: And asking reminded me to go find my kittel, glad I looked, since my wife had moved it somewhere only she knows about.  :)